# Trouble Extracting Text and Clicking Pagination Buttons with Selenium for Audible Audiobook Scraping

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, pagination

I'm using Selenium to scrape details about the audiobooks from:
https://www.audible.com/search

This is the code I've used for pagination

```
pagination = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//ul[contains(@class, "pagingElements")]') 
pages = pagination.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')
last_page = int(pages[-2].text)
```

However, if i try to print the text from elements in pages, i get blanks. The length of pages is 6, so the driver is properly locating the pagination elements on the webpage but is unable to extract the text from the buttons. I also can't click on the button that goes to the next page. Here's the code for that part:

```
next_page = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(@class, "nextButton")]')
next_page.click()
```

Comment: Text of what elements are you trying to get? Can you please share locator(s)?

Comment: _unable to extract the text from the buttons_: Update the question with the text based HTML of the element.

Answer (score 0):

- If your purpose is to scrape the data from multiple pages and that's why you are trying to click on the next page then it's not needed.
- There's another workaround to paginate without the need to click on the next page.

You may try this way:

```py
from typing import List, Dict
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

class AudioBooks:
    def __init__(self):
        options = ChromeOptions()

        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

        self.driver = Chrome(options=options)
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        self.base_url = "https://www.audible.com/search?pageSize=50"

    def page_parser(self) -> List[Dict]:
        
        page_data = []
        products = self.wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'li.bc-list-item.productListItem')))

        for product in products:
            title = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h3.bc-heading.bc-color-link').text
            product_url = product.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h3.bc-heading.bc-color-link>a').get_attribute('href')
            # Similarly, you can parse other details of a product

            page_data.append({"title": title, "product_url": product_url})

        return page_data

    def scrape_single_page(self, page_number: int) -> List[Dict]:
        
        print(f"scraping page {page_number}....")
        self.driver.get(f"{self.base_url}&page={page_number}")

        return self.page_parser()

    def scrape_multiple_page(self, pages: int) -> List[Dict]:
        
        final_data = []

        for page in range(1, pages+1):
            print(f"scraping page {page}....")
            self.driver.get(f"{self.base_url}&page={page}")

            final_data += self.page_parser()

        return final_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = AudioBooks()
    # print(obj.scrape_single_page(page_number=2))
    print(obj.scrape_multiple_page(pages=3))
```

output:

```
scraping page 1....
scraping page 2....
scraping page 3....
[{'title': 'The Way I Hate Him', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/The-Way-I-Hate-Him-Audiobook/B0CCB5X1RZ?qid=1691029526&sr=1-1&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_1&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Tucker', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Tucker-Audiobook/B0CD9QBCCR?qid=1691029526&sr=1-2&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_2&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'A Thousand Li: The Third Cut: A Xianxia Cultivation Novel', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/A-Thousand-Li-The-Third-Cut-A-Xianxia-Cultivation-Novel-Audiobook/B0CD87X8F3?qid=1691029526&sr=1-3&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_3&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Cast in Shadows', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Cast-in-Shadows-Audiobook/B0CD89NT3S?qid=1691029526&sr=1-4&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_4&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'The One I Want', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/The-One-I-Want-Audiobook/B0CC366SW7?qid=1691029526&sr=1-5&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_5&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Like a River', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Like-a-River-Audiobook/B0BTMYRHBJ?qid=1691029526&sr=1-6&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_6&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Mad Boys', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Mad-Boys-Audiobook/B0CD9JFFB8?qid=1691029526&sr=1-7&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_7&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Tom Lake', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Tom-Lake-Audiobook/B0BQ161QW5?qid=1691029526&sr=1-8&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_8&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Manslayer', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Manslayer-Audiobook/B0CBSQQP9G?qid=1691029526&sr=1-9&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_9&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'The SHTF Omnibus Series, Books 1-4', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/The-SHTF-Omnibus-Series-Books-1-4-Audiobook/B0CD87FL41?qid=1691029526&sr=1-10&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_10&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Whisper of Iron 2', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Whisper-of-Iron-2-Audiobook/B0CD973BQ8?qid=1691029526&sr=1-11&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_11&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'The Fifth Kind: Arrival', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/The-Fifth-Kind-Arrival-Audiobook/B0CD88HGFJ?qid=1691029526&sr=1-12&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_12&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Nine of a Kind', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Nine-of-a-Kind-Audiobook/B0CD885PBM?qid=1691029526&sr=1-13&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_13&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'The Saad Truth About Happiness', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/The-Saad-Truth-About-Happiness-Audiobook/B0C9VQG9W5?qid=1691029526&sr=1-14&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_14&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Dark Future', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Dark-Future-Audiobook/B0CCGQ27L5?qid=1691029526&sr=1-15&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_15&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Just Another Missing Person', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Just-Another-Missing-Person-Audiobook/B0BPZVYB35?qid=1691029526&sr=1-16&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_16&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Signature of You', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Signature-of-You-Audiobook/B0CCZK97Z3?qid=1691029526&sr=1-17&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_17&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Out of Nowhere', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Out-of-Nowhere-Audiobook/B0BV4WR9Q5?qid=1691029526&sr=1-18&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_18&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'The Ultimate 90s Alternative Rock Quiz Book', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/The-Ultimate-90s-Alternative-Rock-Quiz-Book-Audiobook/B0CD2WD8HN?qid=1691029526&sr=1-19&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_19&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'American Prometheus', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/American-Prometheus-Audiobook/B002V0PYYE?qid=1691029526&sr=1-20&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_20&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Cursed Cocktails', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Cursed-Cocktails-Audiobook/B0CDCN7DB5?qid=1691029526&sr=1-21&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_21&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'A Stitch in Time', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/A-Stitch-in-Time-Audiobook/B0C8VHYFJ5?qid=1691029526&sr=1-22&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_22&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Legend of the Ice Demon', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Legend-of-the-Ice-Demon-Audiobook/B0CD2YF2J2?qid=1691029526&sr=1-23&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_23&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Searching for Risk', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Searching-for-Risk-Audiobook/B0CD8N8YQK?qid=1691029526&sr=1-24&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_24&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'The Handsy Collection: Man Hands 1-3', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/The-Handsy-Collection-Man-Hands-1-3-Audiobook/B0CD8V8KHQ?qid=1691029526&sr=1-25&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_25&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Castle Town 6', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Castle-Town-6-Audiobook/B0CDCMC633?qid=1691029526&sr=1-26&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_26&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'The Subtle Art of Not Giving a F*ck', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/The-Subtle-Art-of-Not-Giving-a-F-ck-Audiobook/B01I28NFEE?qid=1691029526&sr=1-27&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_27&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Renegades: Harrowmaster', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Renegades-Harrowmaster-Audiobook/B0CBSQ757B?qid=1691029526&sr=1-28&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_28&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Book 1", 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Harry-Potter-and-the-Sorcerers-Stone-Book-1-Audiobook/B017V4IM1G?qid=1691029526&sr=1-29&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_29&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Fortune Teller', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Fortune-Teller-Audiobook/B0C66JJGK8?qid=1691029526&sr=1-30&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_30&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Divide', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Divide-Audiobook/B0CCZS41Z5?qid=1691029526&sr=1-31&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_31&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Too Late', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Too-Late-Audiobook/B0C8ZSQ21Q?qid=1691029526&sr=1-32&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_32&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'The Bonus Room', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/The-Bonus-Room-Audiobook/B0CCWSKXY1?qid=1691029526&sr=1-33&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_33&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'The Silmarillion', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/The-Silmarillion-Audiobook/B0C5MPMQYX?qid=1691029526&sr=1-34&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_34&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Dragons of Fate', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Dragons-of-Fate-Audiobook/B0BPF1LKHB?qid=1691029526&sr=1-35&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_35&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Fourth Wing', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Fourth-Wing-Audiobook/B0BVD25SYT?qid=1691029526&sr=1-36&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_36&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'The Covenant of Water', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/The-Covenant-of-Water-Audiobook/B0BVDVR6XT?qid=1691029526&sr=1-37&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_1_37&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=KVHQH119KGQC95QY44TT&pageLoadId=MdqK3OBQgpcEq0SY&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'},.....{'title': 'Blood of Elves', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Blood-of-Elves-Audiobook/B00XV1ALO0?qid=1691029544&sr=1-140&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_3_40&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=60YGW53PJVRW2WK7JP0X&pageLoadId=A7n6FPLm2U0bBHGZ&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': "Man's Search for Meaning", 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Mans-Search-for-Meaning-Audiobook/B002V0QUOC?qid=1691029544&sr=1-141&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_3_41&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=60YGW53PJVRW2WK7JP0X&pageLoadId=A7n6FPLm2U0bBHGZ&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Spare', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Spare-Audiobook/B0BJ4X9D2F?qid=1691029544&sr=1-142&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_3_42&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=60YGW53PJVRW2WK7JP0X&pageLoadId=A7n6FPLm2U0bBHGZ&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': "In Harm's Way", 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/In-Harms-Way-Audiobook/B01KIQGXWO?qid=1691029544&sr=1-143&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_3_43&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=60YGW53PJVRW2WK7JP0X&pageLoadId=A7n6FPLm2U0bBHGZ&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': "Can't Hurt Me", 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Cant-Hurt-Me-Audiobook/B07KKMNZCH?qid=1691029544&sr=1-144&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_3_44&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=60YGW53PJVRW2WK7JP0X&pageLoadId=A7n6FPLm2U0bBHGZ&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Mayor of Elf Town 5', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Mayor-of-Elf-Town-5-Audiobook/B0CCYZF4FM?qid=1691029544&sr=1-145&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_3_45&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=60YGW53PJVRW2WK7JP0X&pageLoadId=A7n6FPLm2U0bBHGZ&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Avatar, The Last Airbender: The Legacy of Yangchen', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Avatar-The-Last-Airbender-The-Legacy-of-Yangchen-Audiobook/B0C9KVKP4P?qid=1691029544&sr=1-146&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_3_46&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=60YGW53PJVRW2WK7JP0X&pageLoadId=A7n6FPLm2U0bBHGZ&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Reckless Thief', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Reckless-Thief-Audiobook/B0CD2X7NYN?qid=1691029544&sr=1-147&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_3_47&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=60YGW53PJVRW2WK7JP0X&pageLoadId=A7n6FPLm2U0bBHGZ&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'The Lost City of Z', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/The-Lost-City-of-Z-Audiobook/B002VA9LKM?qid=1691029544&sr=1-148&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_3_48&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=60YGW53PJVRW2WK7JP0X&pageLoadId=A7n6FPLm2U0bBHGZ&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Wool', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Wool-Audiobook/B0BKR3Y6SP?qid=1691029544&sr=1-149&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_3_49&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=60YGW53PJVRW2WK7JP0X&pageLoadId=A7n6FPLm2U0bBHGZ&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}, {'title': 'Rich Dad Poor Dad', 'product_url': 'https://www.audible.com/pd/Rich-Dad-Poor-Dad-Audiobook/B008BT3C1Q?qid=1691029544&sr=1-150&ref=a_search_c3_lProduct_3_50&pf_rd_p=83218cca-c308-412f-bfcf-90198b687a2f&pf_rd_r=60YGW53PJVRW2WK7JP0X&pageLoadId=A7n6FPLm2U0bBHGZ&creativeId=0d6f6720-f41c-457e-a42b-8c8dceb62f2c'}]
```

**Few Things to note**:

- By default, the website https://www.audible.com/search contains a minimum of **20** products per page.
- The website has page settings to view the number of products per page which are 20, 30, 40, and 50.
- You might notice, it passes the page number info into the URL.
- So, we can utilize it to load the maximum number of products per page and the new URL would be https://www.audible.com/search?pageSize=50
- Similar to the `pageSize`, it also passes the info about the page number into the URL and the new URL for this would be https://www.audible.com/search?pageSize=50&page=2  (2 for page number 2)

**reference**:

- https://github.com/ajeet214/Web_Scraping_with_Selenium/blob/main/audible_com.py